# 弊社側購入ページにPayPalボタンを設置し、ボタンからPayPalに移動時にエラーになる

Tags: html, wordpress, paypal

ご担当者様
お世話になります。PayPalの導入をしたばかりで現在WebサイトにPayPalボタンをHTMLで設置する作業を進めています。

ボタンにドロップダウンメニューから数を選択するような設定をし、そのHTMLを弊社側商品サイトに貼り付けました。商品サイトでは正しく表示されますが、ボタンを押してPayPalにジャンプしたときに「申し訳ありませんが、現在問題が起きているようです。しばらくしてから再度お試しください。」と表示されます。
問題解決方法を教えてください。

テレメディカ藤木

Comment: おそらく何か勘違いをされているようですが、こちらはPayPalのサポートセンターではありませんよ。

Comment: [開発者向けTOP(導入方法・技術情報) 実装サポート](https://www.paypal.com/jp/webapps/mpp/developer)の最後に「サポート 技術情報の掲示板QiitaやStackoverflow,　サポートをご紹介しています。」の文言が書いてあり、PayPal側は意識しているようです。SPRESENSEの例もありますし。ただ、ここがダイレクト(あるいは専用)なPayPalサポート窓口というのは間違いなので、質問者さんには質問の言い回しは注意してもらいたいところですね。ちなみにもう1年半来ていないようですが、この[PP_MTS_Frank](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/15576/pp-mts-frank)さんが3年前にFAQのような自己回答Q&Aを何件か書かれているようです。

Comment: @user36681 さん、具体的にどのページからどうやって作成されたHTMLなのかを追記していただけませんでしょうか。第三者でも問題を再現しやすいように、たとえば手順を箇条書きするなどして書いてくださると回答が集まりやすいです。質問文下の「編集」から追記できますので、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 表示されているメッセージの通り、一時的な(PayPal側での)問題である可能性もあるので、まずはしばらく待ってから状況を確認すべきかなとも思います。